# How to test Laravel Api (only) Controllers with PEST Php testing?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, pestphp

I've setup a backend only Laravel app from the boilerplate. I want to test the API controllers using Pest, however, I keep getting   `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $request ]] in class Illuminate\Http\Client\Request`.

```
// UserControllerTest.php

use App\Models\User;
use function Pest\Laravel\{getJson, actingAs};
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

// Necessary to access Laravel testing helpers and database factory stuff
uses(
    Tests\TestCase::class,
    RefreshDatabase::class
);

// Auto set up a new authed user for each test
beforeEach(function() {
    actingAs(User::factory()->create());
});

/**
 * Test that the user can be retrieved and api succeeds
 */
it('Test get user succeeds', function () {
    // Should get the user from the user controller
    $response = getJson('api/user');

    // Response should contain a user and be within the 200 range
    $response->assertStatus(200);
});
```

Below is the user controller, just returns the logged in user from the request.

```
UserController.php

    use Illuminate\Http\Client\Request;

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Show the current logged in user
        $user = $request->user();

        return new UserResource($user);
    }
```

My return response is a 500 server error

```
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.
  
  The following exception occurred during the last request:
  
  Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $request ]] in class Illuminate\Http\Client\Request in /home/sites/my-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1118
  Stack trace:
  #0 /home/sites/my-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1027): Illuminate\Container\Container->unresolvablePrimitive(Object(ReflectionParameter))
```

Has anyone used Pestphp to test api only laravel controllers? Is there something that needs to be mocked to test an api route with PEST?

## Edit

This [Testing Laravel API with Pest](https://hashnode.com/post/testing-laravel-api-with-pest-framework-cky5jfawk02fr5ns16rgfdeep) article is quite similar in structure, where they'd just use the     `$response = $this->getJson("/api/posts/{$post->id}");` to get the JSON response, however they don't have the same issue as me.

API Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::apiResource('user', UserController::class);
}
//  GET|HEAD api/user =>user.index › UserController@index
```

**Addition Tests**

Seems it's due to there being no `\Illuminate\Http\Client\Request  $request` when calling `getJson('api/user');

Trying to get a specific user, where there's no `$request` param in the controller works.

```
// This works fine. No error like above.
it('Test get user succeeds', function () {
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    // Should get the user from the user controller
    $response = getJson('api/user/' . $user->id);

    // Response should contain a user and be within the 200 range
    $response->assertStatus(200);
});
```

#### Versions

```
Laravel 9.19
```

Comment: I am absolutely ignorant about PEST and I think it adds no value at all compared to using PHPUnit, but you can check my profile and see some links about how to test, and how to test controllers. But I do see they are using `$this->get(...)`, why are you using a function called `getJson` instead of `$this->getJson(...)`?

Comment: `use function Pest\Laravel\{getJson, actingAs};` imports the getJson call, so you don't need to reference it with `$this`. Effectively, it's just a helper in JEST. `get` is for html pages, but I need to api responses, hence why `getJson`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was I imported the incorrect `Request $request` class in my UserController

```
// Wrong Request Class
// use Illuminate\Http\Client\Request;

// Proper Request Class
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```